# ipywidgets: GridspecLayout grid gap doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ipywidgets

Here is some code that creates a `GridspecLayout` object within an `Accordion` widget.

```
import ipywidgets as ipy
from IPython.display import display

FIELDS = {
    'ssh_key_path': ('SSH Key Path', ''),
    'email': ('Email', ''),
    'ssh_passphrase': ('SSH Passphrase', ''),        
    'database': ('Database', 'DASH_MFG_PROD'),
    'role': ('Role', 'PUBLIC'),
    'schema': ('Schema', 'PUBLIC')
}

widgets = {}

widgets['grid'] = ipy.GridspecLayout(2, 2)

widgets['connect'] = ipy.Button(
                    description='CONNECT',
                    icon='snowflake-o',
                    button_style='success')
widgets['clear'] = ipy.Button(
                    description='CLEAR',
                    icon='eraser',
                    button_style='warning')

widgets['grid'][0, :] = ipy.HBox(children=[widgets['connect'], widgets['clear']], layout=ipy.Layout(height='45px'))

vbox_widgets = []
for field_name, field_tuple in FIELDS.items():
    widget_descp = field_tuple[0]           
    layout = ipy.Layout(height='auto', width='125px')
    label = ipy.Label(widget_descp, layout=layout)            
    widget_default = field_tuple[1]
    if field_name == 'ssh_passphrase':
        layout = ipy.Layout(height='auto', width='90%')
        text_box = ipy.Password(
            value='password',
            placeholder='Enter password',
            layout=layout,
            disabled=False)
    else:
        layout = ipy.Layout(height='auto', width='90%')
        text_box = ipy.Text(
            disabled=False,
            layout=layout,
            value=widget_default)
    widgets[field_name] = ipy.HBox(children=[label, text_box])
    vbox_widgets.append(widgets[field_name])
widgets['grid'][1, 0] = ipy.VBox(children=vbox_widgets)

widgets['logger_label'] = ipy.Label(value="LOG OUTPUT")
widgets['logger_text'] = ipy.Textarea(disabled=False, layout=ipy.Layout(width='99%', height='100%'))
widgets['logger_text'].value = "Fill in the Snowflake credentials and conneciton details and hit the 'CONNECT' button"
widgets['logger_vbox'] = ipy.VBox(children=[widgets['logger_label'], widgets['logger_text']])

widgets['grid'][1, 1] = widgets['logger_vbox']
widgets['grid'].grid_gap = '1px'
accordion = ipy.Accordion(children=[widgets['grid']])
accordion.set_title(0, 'Configuration')
display(accordion)
```

The code displays the following when the accordion is opened:

[image: Accordion with GridspecLayout object]

My issue is the large whitespace between the first grid row(the buttons `Hbox` widget) and the second grid row.  I have explicitly set the `grid_gap` to "1px" but no luck.  I checked the CSS properties using the Firefox inspector and the `HBox` widget is the correct height:

[image: HBox CSS]

Can someone help explain why there is so much dead whitespace between the first row and the second row?

thx

Answer (score 1):

The GridSpecLayout automatically gives you equally sized grid cells, so the top left cell (which holds your two buttons) has grown to the same size as the bottom left cell which holds many more widgets.

I don't know if you could have different sized rows on your gridspec; you could just use a 1x2 grid and a VBox on top for your buttons:

```py
import ipywidgets as ipy
from IPython.display import display

FIELDS = {
    'ssh_key_path': ('SSH Key Path', ''),
    'email': ('Email', ''),
    'ssh_passphrase': ('SSH Passphrase', ''),        
    'database': ('Database', 'DASH_MFG_PROD'),
    'role': ('Role', 'PUBLIC'),
    'schema': ('Schema', 'PUBLIC')
}

widgets = {}

widgets['grid'] = ipy.GridspecLayout(1, 2)

widgets['connect'] = ipy.Button(
                    description='CONNECT',
                    icon='snowflake-o',
                    button_style='success')
widgets['clear'] = ipy.Button(
                    description='CLEAR',
                    icon='eraser',
                    button_style='warning')

# widgets['grid'][0, :] = 

vbox_widgets = []
for field_name, field_tuple in FIELDS.items():
    widget_descp = field_tuple[0]           
    layout = ipy.Layout(height='auto', width='125px')
    label = ipy.Label(widget_descp, layout=layout)            
    widget_default = field_tuple[1]
    if field_name == 'ssh_passphrase':
        layout = ipy.Layout(height='auto', width='90%')
        text_box = ipy.Password(
            value='password',
            placeholder='Enter password',
            layout=layout,
            disabled=False)
    else:
        layout = ipy.Layout(height='auto', width='90%')
        text_box = ipy.Text(
            disabled=False,
            layout=layout,
            value=widget_default)
    widgets[field_name] = ipy.HBox(children=[label, text_box])
    vbox_widgets.append(widgets[field_name])
widgets['grid'][0, 0] = ipy.VBox(children=vbox_widgets)

widgets['logger_label'] = ipy.Label(value="LOG OUTPUT")
widgets['logger_text'] = ipy.Textarea(disabled=False, layout=ipy.Layout(width='99%', height='100%'))
widgets['logger_text'].value = "Fill in the Snowflake credentials and conneciton details and hit the 'CONNECT' button"
widgets['logger_vbox'] = ipy.VBox(children=[widgets['logger_label'], widgets['logger_text']])

widgets['grid'][0, 1] = widgets['logger_vbox']
widgets['grid'].grid_gap = '1px'


children = [
    ipy.HBox(children=[widgets['connect'], widgets['clear']]),
    widgets['grid'],
]
accordion = ipy.Accordion(
    children=[ipy.VBox(children = children)]
)

accordion.set_title(0, 'Configuration')
display(accordion)
```